# Unicellular compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

An operator $T$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$ is called *unicellular* if any two closed invariant subspaces $M$ and $N$ are comparable; that is either $M\subseteq N$ or $N\subseteq M$. There are many examples of (compact) unicellular operators, for example, the Volterra operator.

I am looking at a weaker property. Namely, the existence of a closed nontrivial invariant subspace $M$ that is *comparable* to all the other closed, invariant subspaces. Obviously, any closed invariant subspace of a unicellular operator satisfies this property. On the other hand, any diagonal operator will not be unicellular and won't satisfy this weaker property either.

In particular, I am interested in compact operators that do not have eigenvalues. My questions are:

1. Are there examples of compact operators without eigenvalues having this weaker property, but are not unicellular?  (I suspect the answer is *Yes*)
2. Does any compact operator without eigenvalues have this weaker property? (I suspect the answer is *No*)

Edit: The question is edited for clarity.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit naive, but how can I see that the Volterra operator is unicellular?

Comment: It is not trivial (as far as I know) that its invariant subspaces are only the obvious ones, the  space of functions that vanish almost everywhere on $[0,a]$ for  $a<1$. The references I could find are old. Donoghue, 1957, The lattice of invariant subspaces of a completely continuous quasinilpotent transformation,  and Sarason, 1965, A remark on the Volterra operator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V\oplus V\in B(L^2(0,1)\oplus L^2(0,1))$, with $V$ being the Volterra operator, is an operator without eigenvalues that does not have your property. The invariant subspaces are $L^2(0,a)\oplus L^2(0,b)$, and for any such space $M=A\oplus B$, we can find another one $N=C\oplus D$, with $C\subsetneq A$, $D\supsetneq B$, unless $M=0, H$.

Comment: I think the invariant subspaces are of the form $L^2(a,1)$, but your argument stands nonetheless.

Comment: @Markus: You are right if we use what is probably the standard definition of $V$; my spaces work for $(Vf)(x)=\int_x^1 f(t)\, dt$ (which is really $V^*$ for the other $V$).

Answer (score 1):

The weaker version of unicellularity does not hold; consider the compact operator $T$ defined on a separable Hilbert space $H$ with orthogonal basis $(e_n)$ by $Te_n=\frac1ne_n$.

Comment: Of course, I wanted to exclude diagonal operators. I will edit my question, for clarity.